# Add persistent bridge and tap in ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, bridge, tunnel, tap

I'm trying to create a bridge whose interface is a tap, both with static IPs, and have them persist across reboots.

In Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS, this could be accomplished by editing /etc/network/interfaces as such:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 0.0.0.0
    bridge_ports tap0

auto tap0
iface tap0 inet static
    address 0.0.0.0
    pre-up /usr/sbin/tunctl -t tap0
```

and running

```sh
brctl addbr br0
tunctl -t tap0
brctl addif br0 tap0
```

on the command line.

Then, when you run `bridge link` you get the following output:

```
4: tap0 state UP : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state
forwarding priority 32 cost 100
```

But since Ubuntu 20.04 has deprecated the use of /etc/network/interfaces in favor of netplan, I don't know how to set it up.

I've tried setting /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yml to the following:

```yaml
...
bridges:
  br0:
    addresses: [0.0.0.0/24]
    gateway4: 10.0.2.15
    nameservers:
      addresses: [8.8.8.8]
```

and running `netplan apply` followed by

```
ip tuntap add mode tap tap0
ip link tap0 master br0
```

I've tried running

```
ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip link set dev br0 up
ip tuntap add mode tpa tap0
ip link set tap0 master br0
```

I've even tried adding tap0 as an ethernet interface in /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml, but no matter what I do, when I run `bridge link`

I get

```
4: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 master br0 state disabled priority 32 cost 100
```

How can I get this configured correctly? I've tried everything I've seen online, and no matter what I do I can't get the tap to go from `state disabled` to `state forwarding`. I'm open to any ideas someone might have. I don't have experience with this type of thing so I'm really at a loss for what the issue even is. Please help

Edit:

I believe the tap is to setup OpenVPN with TAP bridging. OpenVPN uses a tap called `tap0` when setup in TAP mode. I'm new to this codebase, and to working with servers/networking in general, and am only working on setting up the server, so to be completely honest don't know *exactly* if there's something else going on.

Comment: I still have no idea how to do this, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you confirmed the displayed "state" value interferes with what you want to accomplish? I would argue a tap currently not forwarding is more correctly described as "disabled" than as "forwarding".

Comment: @anx yes, in the servers on Ubuntu 14.04 that are up and configured correctly, the output of `bridge link` is `4: tap0 state UP : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added the `ip link add` and `brctl addif` to my `/etc/rc.local` script.

Comment: You done it manually? Hmm... it's sad tho.. so netplan doesn't have any capabilities for it? Even redhat NMCLI better than this

Comment: `nmcli` is unable to bring up the interface. No idea why: you'd think the result would be the same.